# php form - godaddy economic hosting Linux

Tags: php, sendmail, shared-hosting

i have this form:

```
<form action="/sendemail.php" id="main-contact-form" method="post" name="contact-form" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="put your name" required="" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" type="email" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..." required="" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Mensaje" required="" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>

<input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
```

and this is sendemail.php:

```
<?php
        $pos = $_POST;
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = $_POST['email']; 
        $to = 'email@gmail.com '; 
        $subject = 'contact message ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message\n $pos";




    mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)



?>
```

the email is arrive empty, i try a lot of stuffs but always comes in the same way, is like the form can´t pass the data from inputs to php variables. im new in php so, any help is welcome.

thanks.

Comment: before send email try show `print_r($body);`, to check if this show the complete text with POST inputs.

Comment: im testing this in godaddy server, in local works fine. so, how can i use print_r in a shared hosting?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
After some research I've found that:

> You need to ask godaddy technical support to enable "sendmail".

[PHP mail() not working on GoDaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252471/php-mail-not-working-on-godaddy)

### ----------

I've tested your code and it **works**. I've received the email with **ALL** the `$_POST` contents without any problems.

```
$pos = $_POST;
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $_POST['email']; 
$to = 'email@gmail.com '; 
$subject = 'contact message ';
```

---

**NOTE:**

1 - `$pos = $_POST;` is an `array` and it will be displayed as `Array`.
2 - Emails sent via `mail()` will most likely end-up on the **spam folder** (read the comments below).

Comment: Why would emails sent via PHP's `mail()` be any different than anything else?

Comment: For example, they don't contain `DKIM-Signature` and `DomainKey-Signature`

Comment: so, how can i display the content of the array?

Comment: @PedroLobito That's not true. Those should be done by your MTA, not by PHP (or any other mail client for that matter). I just sent myself an email using PHP's `mail()` and it was correctly signed, so if you're getting different results you have something misconfigured.

Comment: @PedroLobito The hosting providers won't enable `mail()` function, 'cause is very insecure, I've that issue 1 years ago.

Comment: I'm telling you this based on several years of experience with different hosting providers, even if what you're saying is true ( and I believe you) what happens in real life is very different and most mail send via `mail()` will be flagged as spam. You should try it for yourself.

Comment: @PedroLobito In my experience, I have had *very* few people say that mails sent to them by PHP went to their spam box, and much less since we set up DKIM a while ago, so maybe the mails you were sending were just more "spammy" than the ones I sent. Anyway, you can put whatever headers you want in the email, so I don't see how the remote server accepting the mail would even be able to tell that it came from a PHP script unless you actually *told* it that it came from PHP. You could also compare headers from PHP and whatever else to see which ones are different and code them in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `mail()` function is so insecure and is a vector attack to send massive spam, don't use anymore, for this reason is better to use PHP Mailer libray.

Create a EMAIL account (example: no-reply@domain.com) in your hosting and after that install this library [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), now you can do this:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: That's funny, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php doesn't say it's deprecated, so what are your sources for saying PHP's `mail()` is insecure?

Comment: Although this function is not deprecated, does not mean it is secure, many websites were poisoned with malicious code then the attacker install a console (REMOTE FILE INCLUSION) and use your server to send spam emails without restrictions, unlike this, using PHPMailer, is necessary a valid account in the server to send emails.

Comment: For these reason, many hosting providers decided block this function, when a provider gives your hosting, he is giving you a shared server where if some website listed in same server is vulnerable, your website will be vulnerable as well. And GMAIL and HOTMAIL, start blocking your emails from your shared server.

Comment: Basically the example you give is when the account has already been compromised and malicious users can get in and install scripts to send spam, so force the users to use a remote SMTP server through a wrapper like PHPMailer. If a malicious user can already log in and upload scripts, what prevents them from using PHPMailer to send spam? Because they don't have the username and password to the remote SMTP server? However these must be stored in plain text somewhere in your script already, so there's ultimately no difference as far as I can see (except for accounts that don't need to send mail).

Comment: That was a simple example, an of the best practices is never save passwords as text-plain, we are in a new age of development and best practices are an obligation, for this reason, use environment variables and strong hashers, and in this case, isn't necessary to be logged to upload file to vulnerables sites. All systems are vulnerable but as developer our work is to have less vulnerabilities, and this example is part of this.

Comment: Since you can send your own headers, then `mail()` is relatively low-level, therefore I guess `mail()` is disabled because of the potential of this function being abused by customers to send out spam mail.
It may not be insecure from the user perspective, but it is probably insecure from the hosting provider perspective. Anyway I have been using Ezc's mail library.